# MVC 4 Windows Authentication does not work, why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have INTERNET Web MVC 4 Project in C#, which locally work fine. Now I need to move project to production with Windows Authentication as INTRANET project.

I read some articles but it does not work for me. It is my first .NET Web application.

Steps I made

=== Step 1 - In **Web.Config** in  tag ===

I deleted authentication tag

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
</authentication>
```

and added

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="DOMAIN\ROLE_Name" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

Role exist in Active Directory and contains User Accounts including my account.

=== Step 2 - In **Global.asax** ===

I added **whole** procedure, I'm not sure if it is right, but I read that I should have that procedure in my code.

```
   public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

=== Step 3 - I added Authorization to Controller ===

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    **[Authorize(Roles = "DOMAIN\\ROLE_Name")]**
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
```

=== Step 4 - I deploy web to IIS ===

(which I have not under control but administrator assured me that is configured properly)

When I hit the URL I'm asking for Login credentials and after login I'm getting Error

```
You are not authorized to view this page
```

Some articles says that I have to change authentication mode in project properties but only properties I have on project are these

[image]

I have feeling that I'm mixing two different approach but I just don't know.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the web server's authentication settings are being set, you can add the following XML to your web.config file ***(Requires at least IIS7 I believe)***.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
          <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
          </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This will instruct the web settings for the application to disable anonymous and use windows authentication instead.

Windows authentication and MVC don't work the best together.  The best way to use them together it to defined in your `web.config`

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="*" /> <!-- Or "?" if you only want authenticated users-->
</authorization>
```

Then fine tune the access with the `AllowAnonymousAttribute` and `AuthorizeAttribute`.  For example, you can have the global filter set with allowed default roles:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute { Roles = "domain\\rolename" });
}
```

With this, all controllers will try to authenticate the user and verify they are in the given role.  If you want everyone, authenticated and unauthenticated users, you can use the `AllowAnonymousAttribute`.  If you decide an action needs different roles or users you can decorate it with the `AuthorizeAttribute`.  Do keep in mind, when you do this, it will override the global one.  So if you defined allowed roles the new attribute won't carry them over.